# Pandas Rolling Python to create new Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe from excel file with data something like this:

```
     A                     B                        Sum A       Sum B
0                                           
1   235353.21333333332                      
2    89160.59999999999                      
3   188382.98666666663                      
4                        104677.1466666667  
5                       207723.25333333333  
6                       170128.02666666667  
7                                 165287.5  
8   44863.200000000004                      
9                                177096.72  
10   97687.71666666666                          655447.7167    824912.6467
11  113207.76333333334                          533302.2667    824912.6467
12                                195151.2      444141.6667    1020063.847
13                       151408.4433333333        255758.68     1171472.29
14                       50865.66999999999        255758.68    1117660.813 
15                       84536.19000000002        255758.68      994473.75
16  217555.28666666665                          473313.9667    824345.7233
17   90395.21666666666                          563709.1833    659058.2233
18           126856.21                          645702.1933    659058.2233
19  125190.61999999998                          770892.8133    481961.5033
```

In excel file, to get Sum A at row 10 it uses `=SUM(A2:A12)` and to get Sum B at row 10 it uses `=SUM(B2:B11)`. Now, I am trying to recreate it by using `.rolling` but it cause **DataError: No numeric types of aggregate**. The following is my code to recreate Sum A and Sum B:

```
df['Sum A'] = df['A'].rolling(10).sum()
df['Sum C'] = df['B'].rolling(10).sum()
```

Any suggestion how should I do it in order to recreate the value in Sum A and Sum B?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
df['Sum A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).rolling(10).sum()
```

Comment: Hi @Quang Hoang, this work and recreate the Sum A column, and I need to change the `rolling(10)` to `rolling(11)` in order to show the same result. But is there way to make the NA to empty column? Should I change to `.fillna(' ')`?

Comment: I don't think you should change `NaN` to `' '` since handling mixed typed data is complicated, as shown in your original code. `NaN` will automatically be converted to empty string when you save to Excel anyway. That said, **yes**, you can chain the above with `fillna('')` to get the empty strings where `NaN` values are.

Comment: Hi @Quang Hoang, I notice there is difference in data when I try it, especially in row 11, in my result I should get `533302.2667` but I got `768655.480000`. Do you know why?

Comment: Note that row 11 is sum from row 2 to row 11.

Comment: If I run it the code to `.rolling(10` I got a similar result but row 9 has a value where I don't want that. Any suggestion on how to make value in row 9 to NaN?

Comment: In my opinion, your data has a redundant row (row 0). You should just drop that row, or specifically force your row `9` to `NaN` with `df.loc[9, 'Sum A'] = np.nan` after the rolling.

Comment: I see, thank you for your guidance and solution. It helps to learn something new and thank you for your time.